# Internal Server Error: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/<id>: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, internal-server-error

After installing Yacht on docker compose with this docker-compose.yml

```
---

version: "3"
services:
  yacht:
    container_name: yacht
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - yacht:/config
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    image: selfhostedpro/yacht

volumes:
  yacht:
```

yacht starts normally with `docker-compose up -d` but the dashboard doesn't load anything, on every page i get this popup error:
[popup error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyYyl.png)

I tried the following things:

- Restarting Yacht
- Manually creating the directory but gave an error "invalid argument"
- rebooting the PC

Do somebody know how to fix?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]; include enough source code of your application to demonstrate the issue, including the code that prints out the string `popup error` and describing the circumstances in which it does so?  Just the Compose file on its own isn't really enough to understand what might be going wrong.  Also remember that access to the host's Docker socket is enough to easily compromise the host, so if this isn't a programming question and you're merely running someone else's image, also consider what it may have done.

Comment: but the source code is only the compose file, create a directory, add this composefile and do docker-compose up -d, docker will pull the yacht image and on the port 8000 you will have the application where i have the popup error